# How to create an undeletable app in Android?

Tags: android, system

At first: Yes I've seen the answers with "device administrator" in similar questions, which doesn't work in this case.

I want to make an app just for me against thieves. I know there are a bunch of them out there, but I don't want to trust a third party with location history. The app should only collect the current position every 2 minutes and upload it to my own server.

But I am aware, that thieves know how to factory reset phones, so I need an option, to make it impossible to delete an app (without flashing a new rom).

My first thought is to flash the app with a custom recovery, to make it part of the rom. But I don't know where I have to put the file (i guess a *.jar or even an executable arm file) and what APIs or syscalls I can still use on that level.

I would be glad if someone knows an answer to this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That is impossible, by definition. Either set up your own custom ROM with your app baked in, or your app can be removed by a factory reset.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Geez, tell that to Samsung.  I swear I can't get rid of half their crap..

Comment: @CommonsWare doesn't the exposed framework (not the app) survive a factory reset from within android?

Comment: The reset doesn't reinstall the rom from scratch, does it? Because if not,  there should be a possibility to make an executable which survives the reset, or am i missing something?

Comment: Some of their binary hooks may survive a factory reset, apparently, which is indicative of a security flaw in Android that hopefully is fixed on newer Android OS releases. That being said, anything related to SDK apps themselves gets wiped out, which is why even in the Xposed scenario, you still have to effectively reinstall most/all of Xposed to get it working again. "The reset doesn't reinstall the rom from scratch, does it?" -- it should be replacing everything from a protected volume, particularly on FDE devices. If it doesn't, again, that's a device or Android flaw.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for this explanation. Could I just remove the "Factory Reset" Option from the Settings? I don't need it and a thieve who knows how to get around this, would also be able to flash a new rom.

Comment: "Could I just remove the "Factory Reset" Option from the Settings?" -- not without a custom ROM. Besides, usually you *want* the device to be reset. That's why we have remote wipe capabilities via the device admin API. Besides, it's not like a thief would know ahead of time that your device has certain characteristics. They'll steal it anyway. What you should be worrying about is what the thief will do once the thief has the device, and IMHO resetting it is the least-worrisome thing they could do (compared to using your installed apps for identity theft).